# how to send images from one activity to other (using file path)

Tags: android, android-intent, imageview

In my app, I am loading images from url's in listview. And onclick of list  item I want to show it on next activity. I can pass bitmap through intent,But considering the size restriction of data that can be send through intent I dont want to send this way.

Anybody knows the better way of passing image from one activity to other.

I have heard about storing image in file and sending filepath using intent But don't know how?Please tell me how can I do it?

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {



    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position,
                        long arg3) {

                    imageview=(ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.icon);
                    description=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.firstLine);
                    rating=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text1);
                    noofDownloads=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text2);
                    noofComments=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text3);
                    imageId=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageIdText);
                    publishdate=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.thirdLine);
                    attribution=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.attributionText);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(PicturesList.this, PictureDetail.class);

   String fileName=description.getText().toString();
                fileclass=new FileClass();
                fileclass.saveImage(bitmap,fileName);

                Intent intent = new Intent(PicturesList.this, PictureDetail.class);
                intent.putExtra("imagePath",fileclass.getPath());


                    intent.putExtra("Description",description.getText());
                    intent.putExtra("Rate",rating.getText());
                    intent.putExtra("Downloads",noofDownloads.getText());
                    intent.putExtra("Comments",noofComments.getText());
                    intent.putExtra("PublishTime",publishdate.getText());


    startActivity(intent);

                }
            });

        }
```

And I have save images from ListAdapter

in

```
getview()
{
String fileName=lolpic.getDescription().toString();
                    FileClass fileclass=new FileClass();
                    fileclass.saveImage(bitmap,fileName);
```

and FileClass.java

```
public class FileClass {

    Picture pic;
    File file;

    public void saveImage(Bitmap myBitmap,String fileName) {

        String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        File myDir = new File(root + "/Pictures");

        String fname = fileName+".png";
        file = new File (myDir, fname);
        if (file.exists ())
        {
            file.delete (); 
        }

        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            //myBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);

            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            myBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
            byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

            out.write(byteArray);
            out.flush();
            out.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public String getPath()
    {
        return file.getPath();
    }
}
```

Comment: You wrote that you load image from its url. Just pass this url through intent as String and load it again in another Activity.

Comment: But again in next activity it will take time to load image.I  want to show it immediately. Do u know how to save image in file?

Comment: I think it's usually the better approach to just pass the meta data of an object or data, instead of the whole bunch of data. Assumed that the passed meta data is unique (like a Guid for UserId's).

Comment: I don't think it's possible to do it more quickly. If you're having too long delay in starting another activity, you can use AsyncTask to load image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this to store image in sdcard

```
void saveImage() {

String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
File myDir = new File(root + "/saved_images");

String fname = "MyImage.jpg";
File file = new File (myDir, fname);
if (file.exists ()) file.delete (); 
try {
       FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
       myBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
       out.flush();
       out.close();

} catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

and next get the image path from `file.getpath()`

and use

```
intent.putExtra("imagePath", file.getpath());
```

to send the image through intent and use

```
String image_path = getIntent().getStringExtra("imagePath");
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image_path);
myimageview.setImageDrawable(bitmap);
```

in your receiving activity to display an image onto the imageview named myimageview

Based on comments, looks like it should be myimageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap) . Didn't test this. But give a try to this also if above doesn't work

Comment: where to write this method.(Inside adapter or anywhere else)

Comment: I got the images in my listview adapter, I write this method in listview.  But I am not getting file reference in my activity class.

Comment: write this in your onitemclicklistener of the list
call saveImage() and intent in your onitemclicklistener and write the method outside the onitemclicklistener method

Comment: k i will try and getback to you

Comment: It is giving file not found exception.    intent.putExtra("imagePath", file.getPath());-Null Pointer exception on this line

Comment: Ya Its get solved. But If I write yhis method in adapter to store all the images.All the images get stored but when I write getPath() to get path it gives null pointer exception.  If I dont write this method in Adapter it works fine.  Why?

Comment: File file will be local to the block when used as u did but it should be reflected in all the other places where you are using the file to get its path. So i asked you to declare it as a global variable

Comment: Ya I Declared it as global variable

Comment: sorry to bother you again but i didnt get the problem you are facing

Comment: when I use your method to save image to the pathy in the same class I am perfectly save it.  But when I write a seperate Util class for your method and use it I got null pointer exception at file.getpath().

Comment: instead of just passing the file name pass the path to the saveImage() and use file.getpath()

Comment: I faces null pointer as well but realise that I had forgotten to add
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />   

Without this, you can't create files to sdcard. Hopes that it will help for those who faces the same problem.

Comment: Thanks for informing that @LeeYiHong. It would be really helpful for many.

Comment: should be  myimageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

Answer (score 2):

**sending Activity**

```
final String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
pathToImage = root + "/my/image/path/image.png";

Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("imagePath", pathToImage);
startActivity(intent);
```

And in you **receiving activity**:

```
String path = getIntent().getStringExtra("imagePath");
Drawable image = Drawable.createFromPath(path);
myImageView.setImageDrawable(image);
```

Comment: how to create file?how to store it inside file